# Please solve Oracle stored procedure error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am learning oracle and i am beginner. Please solve my following error.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SP_SALE_SELECT
( para1 OUT NVARCHAR2
, para2 OUT NVARCHAR2
, action IN NVARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
  IF action = 1 then
    Select * From VI_Sale;
  Else if action = 2 then
    Select * From VI_Sale
    WHERE SaleID = para1;
  Else if action = 3 then
    Select * From VI_Sale
    Where CustomerID = para1;
  Else if action = 4 then
    Select * From VI_Sale
    where SaleID = para1 and CustomerID = para2;
 End if;
END SP_SALE_SELECT;
```

> Error(20,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SP_SALE_SELECT" when
>   expecting one of the following:     if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `ELSE IF` instead of `ELSEFIF` (no space) so you are creating additional ifs which you should close.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SP_SALE_SELECT
( para1 OUT NVARCHAR2
, para2 OUT NVARCHAR2
, action IN NVARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
  IF action = 1 THEN
    Select * From VI_Sale;
  ElSEIF action = 2 THEN
    Select * From VI_Sale
    WHERE SaleID = para1;
  ElSEIF action = 3 THEN
    Select * From VI_Sale
    Where CustomerID = para1;
  ELSEIF action = 4 then
    Select * From VI_Sale
    where SaleID = para1 and CustomerID = para2;
 End if;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change each `Else if` to an `ELSIF`. Also, you can't just select * from a table in a PL/SQL block, you will need to select into a variable(s). E.g.,

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SP_SALE_SELECT
( para1 OUT NVARCHAR2
, para2 OUT NVARCHAR2
, action IN NVARCHAR2
) AS
v_col1 VI_Sale.col1%type;
BEGIN
  IF action = 1 then
    Select col1 into v_col1 From VI_Sale;
  Elsif action = 2 then
    Select col1 into v_col1 From VI_Sale
    WHERE SaleID = para1;
  Elsif action = 3 then
    Select col1 into v_col1 From VI_Sale
    Where CustomerID = para1;
  Elsif action = 4 then
    Select col1 into v_col1 From VI_Sale
    where SaleID = para1 and CustomerID = para2;
 End if;
END SP_SALE_SELECT;
```

Comment: v_col1 VI_Sale.col1%type;
Is this mean select 1 field or all fields? If i want to select 1 or more fields, please tell me how to select.

Comment: This just selects one column, for two you do 'select col1, col2 into v_col1, v_col2' etc. The 'v_col1 VI_Sale.col1%type;' line is just defining the variable to be the same type as the col1 column of your table.